# Showing modal on successfully posting data from redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

Hey guys i am using React Hooks with redux, so what i want is lets say user need a signup on my website, so after posting his details i am sending back status :200 and if it has status:200 i am updating a state value in my userReducer like say "status" to true (which initially was false) and based on this boolean value i am showing a modal to user with  the message. So code goes like

Actions.js

```
export const userRegisterAction = (data: any) => async (dispatch: any) => {
  console.log(data);
  axios.post("http://localhost:4000/register_user", data).then((res) => {
    console.log("hittinh server");
    console.log(res.data);
    if (res.data.status == 200) {
      dispatch({
        type: USER_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    } else {
      dispatch(errorActions());
    }
  });
};
```

Reducer.js

```
case USER_REGISTRATION_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        status: true,
        info: action.payload.doc.ops[0],
      };
```

and then in my component

```
const user = useSelector((state: RootState) => {
    console.log(state.user.info);
    console.log(state.error.iserror);
    return { user: state.user };
  });
<IonAlert
              isOpen={user.user.status == true}
              cssClass="my-custom-class"
              header={"User Registered!"}
              backdropDismiss={false}
              // subHeader={'User Registered !'}
              message={"You have been registered successfully."}
              // buttons={["OK"]}
              buttons={[
                {
                  text: "OK",
                  handler: () => {
                    console.log("Confirm Okay");
                    redirect();
                  },
                },
              ]}
            />
```

Note. I am using redux persist and this reducer needs to be persisted for future purpose as i am gonna use this wherever i need user related task like if he needs to change password i will pick up the email from my user reducer so it doesnt gets lost on refresh

NOW COMING TO THE ISSUE, as my reducer state is persisted once the "status" is true if user wishes to signup from another account as soon as he goes to signup page he will again see the result of "ionAlert" as it will match the condition status==true , so what i am doing is on every unmount i am dispatching action which sets "status" to false, although this works fine, but i wanna know is this the correct approach , how are you all dealing with this stuff ??

Comment: Do not use user status to show this modal. This modal indicates the outcome of the registration process so add separate state

Comment: ya cool that staus was just for reference , i am using here another state name , i just wanna know abt the approach :)

Comment: Use special state just for this modal. This state should be set to `true` when you display the modal and to `close` when you close it. That's it.

Alternatively you can use local state in the component, so it wouldn't be persisted

Comment: hmm seems fine, tq

Comment: @АлексейМартинкевич just to clear up u saying me to create a new reducer for modal ?

Comment: Yeap, exactly. It's also an option to have one generic reducer for all modals.